# Passing a Matrix from C++ to MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix

I've reviewed questions with similar (almost identical title) but found no definitive answer, so I will restate the question very simply.

I am trying to pass a Matrix (multidimentional array, where both dimensions are superior to 1) from C++ to MATLAB. I've checked it and it's just fine in C++ but after **engPutVariable** is executed and I check the entries of the MATLAB variable, the entries are the same but scrambled with no dicernable pattern; some elements remain, others are zeroed, etc.

**I would like to know what is the correct way of passing a matrix from C++ to MATLAB space. Thank you.**

The matrix is supposed to be simply:

1  2  3  4  5

6  7  8  9  10

11 12 13 14 15

16 17 18 19 20

But...

Here are the rows of my matrix plotted at regular intervals.
[image: Here are the rows of my matrix plotted at regular intervals]

Here is the matrix after passing it to MATLAB.
[image: Here is the matrix after passing it to MATLAB]

Right now my best guess is that I am not preparing the data structure correctly in C++, but I haven't been able to find any good tutorial for that either... here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "engine.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int dim = 5; double i = 1.0;
    Engine *ep;

    mxArray *RESPONSE = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(dim, dim, mxREAL);
  mxArray *SVD_W = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(2, dim, mxREAL);

    double *r_pointer = mxGetPr(RESPONSE);
  double *s_pointer = mxGetPr(SVD_W);

  for(int n=0;n<dim;++n)
  {
    for(int l=0;l<dim;++l)
    {
      r_pointer[n*l+l] = i; //A matrix is filled/accessed as a linear array.
      i+=1.0;
    }
    s_pointer[n] = i;
  }

    if (!(ep = engOpen(""))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nCan't start MATLAB engine\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    engPutVariable(ep, "RESPONSE", RESPONSE);
  engPutVariable(ep, "SVD_W", SVD_W);
    engEvalString(ep, "efit_plot;");

    printf("Hit return to finish\n\n");
    fgetc(stdin);

    mxDestroyArray(RESPONSE);
  mxDestroyArray(SVD_W);
    engEvalString(ep, "close;");
    engClose(ep);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Is the data in row-column vs. column-row order?  Transposed across the diagonal?

Comment: @RobL I've checked that posibility already, it's not. I was first outputting the matrix as a table and when I saw the mess I though writetable was messing things around so I tried to plot the matrix to see the points (I'm using a test 5x5 matrix filled with linearly increasing integers (they are double but I started at 1.0 and increase by one on each iteration) and I get some kind of irregular sawtooth for all rows but the first which actually contains the last row of the matrix since it displays as a decreasing line on the graph.

Comment: Isn't matrix values in MATLAB double-precision floating point by default?

Comment: Yeah, yeah, what I mean is the correct matrix should look very simple.

Comment: `r_pointer[n*l+l]` doesn't look right. You have to have `n*dim+l`

Comment: Yes, that's my best lead still... I'm probably tired, not doing the math right but... on row n=0 index should run normally. Then for n=1 it's....AH.... clearly... I don't know how this happened... how embarrassing ^^~

Comment: Now I feel bad just adding to the spam regarding this false problem...